# Full disk space that went away on reboot?

Tags: disk-usage

So I was checking my website where I noticed that it wouldn't load, so I checked the VPS and everything seemed fine, until I did `df` and saw that the disk was full.
I searched everywhere to see what file or folder could be making it full and couldn't find anything.
Then I decided to reboot the VPS and as soon as it started again the disc was back to normal with only 5GB used.

What could have caused the disk to fill like that? Is there something I can do to prevent it?
Things I have installed are, NGinx, Daemon and Jenkins.

Comment: Sounds like you had lots of stuff in `/tmp`. That directory gets emptied when you reboot. No idea how to check what the original cause was though, other than to specifically check stuff in there the next time you run into the issue. Note that you might need elevated privileges (sudo) to list some directories in there.

Comment: @ByteCommander It's what I thought too, but at the time that didn't come into mind. If it happens again I'll make sure to check with sudo.

Comment: A file that's open for writing won't show up to `ls` until it's closed. Some process you'running ("NGinx, Daemon and Jenkins") is doing an unconstrained write to a file. Use `sudo lsof` just before the disk fills up, and look for the file. `sudo lsof / | awk '\''{if($7 > 1048576) print $7/1048576 "MB" " " $9 }'\'' | sort -n -u`